# Black and white horror movie where people have a mark on their palm and become voodoo-resurrected

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, voodoo

I'm searching this movie for years.  It starts inside a cafe, I think, on a rainy night.  The protagonist sees his recently deceased brother passing outside. It has to do with a voodoo cult, people when they die they melt like wax. It's in urban environment for what i remember. Ends with some guy waving to the protagonist with a mark in his palm, meaning that the cult is not dead.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Can you estimate when (maybe based on how the city looked) it might have been filmed?

Comment: Hi! I saw it on TV mid 80's but the movie was much older, black and white as i mentioned. I have no idea about the city, i state pretty much all i can remember in the description. Not much, i know....